# Format/standard for mathematical equations

Tags: math, standards

I'm developing web framework that will be able to communicate via web services with many different programming languages. There will be mathematical equations that must be able to be computed in different languages. I was wondering if there is already some kind of standard or format for transferring mathematical equations, maybe as XML or other format?

For example, if I have following equation (this is simple, but could be more complex)

(a * b^2) / 2

Then in programming language I would just give a is 4 and b is 3 and then program would be able to calculate equation and give result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathml) is what you are looking for, in particular *Content MathML*.

Comment: As usual, HPM is spot on.  But if you're going to transfer these equations your clients will have to be able to parse and understand LaTeX notation.